# Assembly in c language

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I have code in assembly form and I want to transform it to С code. So far I am aware of the fact that A decoder is needed. I have download the rtdec but I can not understand how to use it in order to transform the code.

The code is :

```
.data
A: 
     .word 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
     .word 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17
     .word 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
     .word 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
B: 
     .word 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17
     .word 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
     .word 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
     .word 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
C:
     .word

.text
     li $8, 0
     li $9, 0
     li $15, 16
     li $16, 4
     la $10, A
     la $11, B
     la $12, C
again:
     lw $13, 0($10)
     lw $14, 0($11)
     add $13, $13, $14
     sw $13, 0($12)
     addi $10, $10,4
     addi $11, $11,4
     addi $12, $12,4
     addi $9, $9,1
     blt $9, $15, again
     li $9,0
     addi $8, $8,1
     blt $8, $16, again
     li $v0, 10
     syscall
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (especially the code part)

Comment: Welcome to SO. We usually don't do other people's homework for them. Are you familiar with the MIPS assembly at all? Do you know what do  those commands do (li, la, add, etc.)? Or do you know where to look it up?

Comment: Thank you. I  want your guidance only not to solve my homework. I am familiar with Mips only at recent time. But I know that commands. I am confused in arrays A and B where the initialization is

Comment: See the answer. Did that help?

Answer (score 1):

The code uses three registers - $10, $11, and $12 - as the current position pointers in the three arrays A, B, and C. Here's the init sequence:

```
 la $10, A
 la $11, B
 la $12, C
```

So $10 follows A, $11 follows B, and $12 follows C. Let's see what else happens to those registers:

- `lw $13, 0($10)` loads the word that $10 is pointing at (the one from A)
- `lw $14, 0($11)` loads the word that $11 is pointing at (the one from B)
- `sw $13, 0($12)` **stores** a register into C

Finally, all three registers are increased by the word size, which is 4:

```
 addi $10, $10,4
 addi $11, $11,4
 addi $12, $12,4
```

That is "move on to the next array element in A, B, and C" logic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! @Seva Alekseyev